# The basis $\beta = \{ e_{\psi(1)},...,e_{\psi(n)} \} $ is equivalent to $\alpha=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ $\iff \text{sgn}(\psi)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be an ordered basis of $V$. Prove that

the basis $\beta = \{ e_{\psi(1)},...,e_{\psi(n)} \} $ is equivalent to $\alpha \iff \text{sgn}(\psi)=1$, where $\psi\in S_n$.

> Two bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equivalent if $\det [\text{Id}]_\alpha^\beta>0$.

I don't know how to prove it rigorously, but here is what I what I am thinking.

$\Leftarrow$ If $ \text{sgn}(\psi)=1$ then $\psi$ is even. Since $\beta$ is a basis, then $\forall e_i\in V$, $e_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $e_{\psi(1)},...,e_{\psi(n)}$.

$$e_i=c_1e_{\psi(1)}+...+c_ne_{\psi(n)}$$

All of the $c_i$s will be zero except for one of them, which will be $1$. Then $e_i=e_{\psi(j)}$.

So, the columns of $ [\text{Id}]_\alpha^\beta$ will be $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ but in a different order. Since $\psi$ is even, then the number columns that got swapped would be even. Hence $\det [\text{Id}]_\alpha^\beta>0$, as swapping $n$ columns of a matrix changes the sign of the determinant if $n$ is odd and preserves it if $n$ is even.

As a result, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equivalent.

$\Rightarrow$ I am not sure about this direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix could be useful

Comment: The determinant is just equal to $\operatorname{sgn}(\psi)$ (think of starting from the identity matrix and permuting the columns according to the permutation $\psi$; the effect on the determinant (because it is an alternating multilinear function of the columns of a matrix) is to introduce a factor of $\operatorname{sgn}(\psi)$), that's why the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Thank you!

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is completely correct and rigorous for the $\impliedby$ direction (although you seem to have some doubt about the rigor, so if you can be more explicit about your doubt then I can add a further comment. To point out one very minor thing, the phrase "the number of columns that got swapped" is ambiguous: it would be better to say "the number of column swap operations" or something like that).

And with only the slightest tweak to your proof of the $\impliedby$ direction, you can prove the $\implies$ direction too, by proving its contrapositive which says

> If $\psi$ is odd then $\text{sgn}(\psi)=-1$.

To prove this, starting from where you write "If $\psi$ is even..." you simply write "If $\psi$ is odd..." and then you follow the implications from that assumption.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful!